# Multiple dc-dc Converters mid-tap on batteries connected in series

Tags: dc-dc-converter, lithium

I want to design a 48v system for an RV with multiple Lithium batteries connected in series (either four 12v or two 24v lithium batteries).

I like the idea of a 48v system to reduce the size of the wires needed for the high output inverter.

I would need 12 volts to run some of the systems on the RV (Fridge, lights, etc).

My question is: Would it be possible to connect two DC-DC converters across each of the 24v battery (or battery sets) instead of using a single 48V-12V converter?  I'm thinking this would make the lower voltage converters more efficient, but I can't figure out what the impact would be on the output end and the balancing load of the batteries.

Answer (score 2):

The batteries would become unbalanced due to possibly drawing more from one series pair than the other... With Lithium batteries this could cause very serious problems...

Don't do this - just use a single 48 to 12V converter.

Comment: Makes sense - I have searched and not found this kind of configuration, but I thought I would get some opinions. I'll stick to a 24V system rather than a 48V one. Sorry about the typo on the title of this post, I meant to say Batteries Connected in Series, not Parallel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What @Solar Mike said, or just run two separate 24v systems.  But running an unevenly configured 48v system as you describe will at best shorten the life of the batteries and at worst cause a fire with the lithium batteries.